# unable to convert string to number

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert string to number but I am unable to do that , 
after passing each number from foreach

```
function sum(num){

 num.toString().split('').forEach(add);

}


function add(value , key) {
    console.log(value);    //  2,3 
   Number(value);
   console.log(typeof(value))   // string string

}


sum(23);
```

In the code  - >

> After I did  Number(value); in function **add(value, key)** I am still getting string  console.log(typeof(value))  // string

Comment: What problem you are facing with this code?

Comment: You should do `var n = Number(value); console.log(typeof(n));`

Comment: check this `const crossSum = num => String(num).split("").reduce((a,b) => a+Number(b), 0);`

Answer (score 2):

You're not assigning it to a new variable / reassigning the variable:

```js
function sum(num){
    num.toString().split('').forEach(add);  
}
   
function add(value , key) {
    console.log( { value } );
    const newValue = Number(value);
    // or alternatively value = Number(value);
    console.log( typeof newValue );
}
   
sum(23);
```